# Problem with complex derivative

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I have to find all points where function $f(z)=\mathbb{Re}z \cdot |z|$ is complex differentiable.

CR equations arent satisfied in points $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

So Im calculating derivative at $0$ from definition:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathbb{Re}z |z|}{z}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r\cos{\phi}\cdot r}{re^{i\phi}}=0$$

So the above function is complex differentiable only at $0$. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. To be really careful, you might want to use the squeeze theorem for the last limit, but it could also be considered obvious.

Comment: im confused. wolfram alpha claims that this fucntion isnt c-differentiable at 0

Comment: That's a computer problem. Perhaps it doesn't deal well with functions differentiable at just one point.

Answer (score 0):

Try the definition of a complex derivative (when $z_{0}$ is real)
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z_{0} \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+z_{0})-f(z)}{z_{0}}
\end{equation}
Notice that the denominator comed from the usual definition where explicitly one would write $z+z_{0}-z$. Feed into this your function and expand, you should start to see the answer pretty early on.

Comment: So what? Is my answer wrong then?

Comment: Well, what do you think? How does the above definition of a complex derivative differ from yours?

Comment: I used the $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ definition... They are equivallent, arent they?